# How to fix Veracode - Cross site scripting - CWE ID 80 - Basic XSS - use of $(item) in .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, veracode

So, when our web application is scanned for Veracode, I get many Cross-Site Scripting flaws,

> "Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)"(CWE ID 80).

And, out of few flaws we have, I could not figure out how to fix this particular scenario.
Below is my piece of code -

```
$(".ui-dialog-buttonset .ui-button:visible").each(function(index, item) {
    var label = $(item).text();
    if (label == "Save" || label == "Create")
        $(item).click();
});
```

I can see flaw reported on `$(item).text();` and `$(item).click();` lines.
I understand that, for text I can use something like `DOMPurify.sanitize` to clean the string.
But, I could not understand, why veracode is reporting for `$(item).click();`
Is it because the `$(item)` itself is not safe?
If yes then, how do I fix it?
I would greatly appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found fix from [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) library.
You can sanitize DOM element too using DOMPurify.
So, below code works -
`item = DOMPurify.sanitize(item, {SAFE_FOR_JQUERY:true});`