# In js file getting Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80)

Tags: javascript, java, veracode

Below line showing veracode issue . I have tried to use encodeURI(`incidentTypeAfterEdit`) and encodeURI(`incidentDescriptionAfterEdit`) but it is getting encoding, functionality not working. Can you plese help me to fix this issue

```
$("#incident-title" + incidentId).html(incidentTypeAfterEdit + " - " + incidentDescriptionAfterEdit);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: According to veracode documentation [https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/80.html] about CWE ID 80, The software receives input, but it doesn't neutralize/incorrectly neutralizes special characters such as "<", ">", and "&" (interpreted as web-scripting elements). So I guess you will need to neutralise the content of incidentTypeAfterEdit. For example, replace any occurrences of "<", ">", and "&", with an empty string, another similar question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612746/how-to-fix-veracode-cross-site-scripting-cwe-id-80-basic-xss-use-of-it?rq=1